# C++ Loop for String

Tags: c++, loops

I am struggling to create a loop for getting input from user. The input must `push_back()` each instance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    vector <string> bookQ = { "what","book","is","that","you","are","reading" };
    for (int i = 0; i < bookQ.size(); i++) {
        cout << bookQ[i] << ' ';        
    }
    cout << endl;
    string input;
    int x = 0;    
    for (x != '1') {                                 // require a loop to input string and  end when user prompts                      
        cout << "Enter 1 to stop" << endl;           //
        cin >> x;                                    //
        getline(cin, input);                         //
        bookQ.push_back(input);                      //
    }                                                //
    for (int i = 0; i < bookQ.size(); i++) {
        cout << bookQ[i] << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: whats wrong with the code? Please include example input, output and expected output in the question

Comment: On your input loop you're using `for (x != '1')`. That should probably be a `while` instead of `for`.

Comment: Error occurs at the loop // (x != '1') " !  <- "not declared and states ";" needs to be added

Comment: That's exactly the problem @jkb mentioned.

Comment: Problem with while loop: Output just runs after any input without end... want the user to input eg. "my book c++" but as "my" then "book" then "c++" and user finished then ends loop

Comment: @Hendrik Did any of the answers help? If you haven't read it, this is good: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `for` loop is missing the declaration and (iteration) expression parts:

```
for (declaration-or-expression; declaration-or-expression; expression)
```

so it should have looked like this:

```
for (;x != '1';) {
```

which is generally written as

```
while (x != '1') {
```

- That would cause problems though since it would not stop directly when the user entered `1`.
- You are also comparing an `int` with a `char` (`'1'`), so in order to exit the loop, the user would have had to enter `49` (the ASCII value for `1`), not `1`.
- You are also mixing formatted input (`cin >> x`) with unformatted input (`getline`). I suggest that you stick to one only.

Example:

```cpp
while(cout << "Enter 1 to stop\n", getline(cin, input) && input != "1") {
    bookQ.push_back(input);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply check if input is 1 everytime the user enters somthing, and when it does = 1, simply break loop.

```
string x;
while (true) {                                 // require a loop to input string and  end when user prompts                      
    cout << "Enter 1 to stop" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    if (x == "1"){
       break;
    }
    getline(cin, x);
    bookQ.push_back(x);
}
}
```

Comment: Still runs indefinitely after first input

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant that input is a string, then you've made a few mistakes with types. First of all, you've used wrong type for variable x, you used int which is integer type, and the type string is required. Secondly, when comparing x with '1' you used single quotes, which define the type of variable as char, not string. To make 1 a string you should use double quotes, like so "1". Besides that, you have used `for(condition)`, which is incorrect syntax. You should use `while(condition)`. Also, when your loop iterates, the x variable is the input book name, and input variable is always an empty string, so I would suggest replace input with x everywhere. The working code is below.

P.S. I am not sure whether you want "1" to be in the final vector, so I haven't changed that

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> bookQ = {"what", "book", "is", "that", "you", "are", "reading"};
    for (int i = 0; i < bookQ.size(); i++) {
        cout << bookQ[i] << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;

    string input;
    string x;
    while (x != "1") {
        cout << "Enter 1 to stop" << endl;
        cin >> x;

        bookQ.push_back(x);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < bookQ.size(); i++) {
        cout << bookQ[i] << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is better than my answer, unfortunately it adds the final `"1"` to the end of the vector.

Answer (score 0):

First, your `for` syntax is wrong. You want a `while` loop instead, or in this case a `do..while` loop would make more sense.  Also, you are pushing the user's input into the vector before validating what the input actually is.

Second, `x` is an integer, but `'1'` is a character whose ASCII value is number 49. Your loop will never end, because `!=` will always be true. Since you want the user to enter number 1 to stop the loop, you need to drop the quotes:

Third, what is the point of pre-populating `bookQ`? Just declare the `bookQ` without any initial data, and then `cout` the entire question as a normal string. This way, after the user is done entering input, the vector will contain *only* the user's input and nothing else.

Try something more like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    vector <string> bookQ;
    string input;

    cout << "what book is that you are reading" << endl;

    do {
        cout << "Enter a book, or 1 to stop" << endl;
        getline(cin >> ws, input);
        if (input == "1") break;
        bookQ.push_back(input);
    }
    while (true);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < bookQ.size(); ++i) {
        cout << bookQ[i] << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```